# How can I replace backslashes into string through JavaScript ?! (Different Question)

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I'm trying to use an Atom editor plugin that returns import path for easily import JS modules.

That works right in Mac and Linux but in windows that returns wrong path.

For example the right path is :

```
import Weather from '../../../helpers/weather';
```

But that returns :

```
import Weather from '..\..\helpers\weather';
```

I've searched about this problem into StackOverflow but those answers didn't help me. because that path return from node.path and I can't replace \ with / and it's not a comfortable solutions to fix this issue.

I've searched about String.raw in ES6 syntax and that didn't help me too.

I want to replace all \ to / into that import path and unfortunately JS can't know \ into an String and I should make a trick to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just fix the plugin?

Comment: @melpomene In office we should use Windows, In atom I can edit plugins. I need this trick for plugin and it's a big question for me :-)

Comment: What is your comment supposed to mean? If you can edit plugins, what's keeping you from fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you might find helpful

https://atom.io/packages/toggle-slash

[image]

Ctrl+Shift+/ Toggle /(or Double it up)
Ctrl+Shift+\ Toggle (or Double it up)

Comment: this plugin helped me. tnx

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]
There is in fact a way through Javascript to do this.
You can use String.replace() function with an easy regex.

```
Str = Str.replace(/\/gi,'/');
```

This won't work indeed, since \ is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript) so you have to add one more like :

```
Str = Str.replace(/\\/gi,'/');    //with escape , replace / by \ globally
```

**You will have to double the \ in your original string, else one \ would just escape the character next to it**

The first answer shall be helpfull , you can also use SublimeText editor to select all / and overwrite //.

But if you want to do it directly with javascript like:

```
var Str = '.\.\.\helpers\weather'; // and double these, I don't know how
```

Test it with this code:

```
var Str = '..\\..\\..\\helpers\\weather';
console.log(Str);
Str = Str.replace(/\\/gi,'/');
console.log(Str);
```

Or create an html file and copy this:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>/ to \</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="p1">Original:   </p>
      <p id="p2">Modified:   </p>
      <script>
         var Str = '..\\..\\..\\helpers\\weather';
          console.log(Str);
          document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML += Str;
         
         Str = Str.replace(/\\/gi,'/');
         console.log(Str); 
          document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML += Str;
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No No , Str should be with \ not /

Comment: So the exact opposite or something else?

Comment: You have written in reverse, str should be with backslash not slash !!!

Comment: Is it okay now ?

Comment: Not really, because as I said that input string is with single backslash and not dissoluble like your code :-(